# Leaflet polyline changes position on zoom

Tags: javascript, leaflet, polyline

I am using leaflet to display diagrams/schematics.

Nodes (or 'icons') on a diagram are based on L.Marker with an L.DivIcon and the lines (or edges) use L.Polyline
I am encountering a problem where the lines change position when I zoom in/out.

For this purpose, I am using a very simple CRS, where the scale is equivalent to the zoom level:

```
L.CRS.VerySimple = L.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, {
   scale: function (zoom) {
      return zoom;
   },

   zoom: function(scale) {
      return scale;
   }
});
```

When the map zooms in/out I scale the markers like so (this is implement in the class extending `L.marker`:

```
 handleZoom(event, map) {
      const scale = map.getZoomScale(map.getZoom(), map.options.zoom);
      const newWidth = this.initialWidth * scale;
      this.iconElem.style.width = `${newWidth}px`;
   },
```

Here it is on initial load (no zoom):

[image]

Here it is after zooming in:

[image]

Can see that the polyline has moved off to the left...

I can see two causes:

1. Leaflets handling of polylines (path) when zooming is not as I expect and I need to explicitly handle the coordinates somehow? (Just to be clear here, I don't want the line to appear 'larger' as for the icons..just appear in the right place)
2. I am not correctly handling scaling of the nodes in the first place?

Comment: Have you tried using `ImageOverlay`s for the "scalable markers" instead?

Comment: Not yet, but I have read about it. The trade-off being that I want the 'nodes' to be draggable, which L.Marker has support for and ImageOverlay does not (as far as I understand).

Comment: I decided to stick with Marker for the component...making sure `iconAnchor` was set to 0,0 ensure that the offset of lines was consistent across all zooms, which finally pointed to an error in calculation the position of the line in the first place, which happened to correspond to the default initial icon anchor offset. phew.